# Permission to synchronize hybris product

Tags: permissions, synchronization, e-commerce, access-rights, sap-commerce-cloud

How do I enable a hybris user group to synchronize individual products on the hMC?

More specifically, I want to enable this button **"Start Synchronization for this product"** on the hMC for users of this user group:

[image]

Preferably, if you could show me how to grant these access rights via impex files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try granting these to the user group to enable that button:

```
Type;UID;MemberOfGroups;Password;Target;read;change;create;remove;change_perm
UserGroup;Mygroup;employeegroup;;;;;;;
;;;;SyncItemCronJob;+;+;+;+
;;;;SynchronizeCatalogVersionWizard;+;+;+;+
```

If you don't want to allow entire catalog synchronization to the group, you can disable the hMC node by adding a hmcXML to the user group, like this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE UserGroup;UID[unique=true];hmcXML
;Mygroup;"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1""?>
<configuration
   xmlns=""hybris.de/schemas/hmc/generic"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
   xsi:schemaLocation=""hybris.de/schemas/hmc/generic hmc.xsd"">

   <explorertree>
      <group name=""catalog"">
         <group name=""catalogviews""           mode=""delete"" />
      </group>
   </explorertree>
</configuration>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can assign permission on an item/instance level.

One way to do it is to disable the catalog sync menu and replace it with a cronjob to do the sync

Comment: I don't really mean specific items/instances. Sorry about that, my fault. The button would be enabled to all products. I said individual products because this button synchronizes one product at a time.